# Data Driven Approach with Jmeter

Tags: functional-programming, jmeter, data-driven

I am using CSV Data Set Config config element to read CSV file. My requirement is to read line if the column value is value is "Y" else want to skip.

JSON Body Data:

```
{
    "UserName": "${Username}",
    "Password": "${Password}"
}
```

CSV File Content:

```
Username,Password,RunTest
testuser,test@123,Y
testuser1,test@12,N
```

Comment: Add a If Controller just before the request, in the Condition, use below syntax: "${RunTest}" == "Y". In Runtime, if the value is Y, it will trigger your HTTP request, else not. Let me know if above works. :)

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Try something first, then come back with a specific question about your code.

Comment: If Controller works. Thanks @NaveenKumarNamachivayam,

Comment: Thanks. I am adding it to the answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a **[If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)** just before the request. In the **Condition**, use the below syntax:

```
"${RunTest}" == "Y"
```

In Run-time, if the value is **Y**, it will trigger your **HTTP request**, else not.